# Is it acceptable to use vulgar profile pics?

Tags: support

Firstly, the user is not a spam user and has some reputation. But the user uses vulgar pic (I feel) as their profile pic. What should be done to such users?

Does the community consider this? How can we handle this?

Comment: Link to the profile please...or flag one of their posts for our attention. Vulgar imagery isn't acceptable on profile pictures, mods can get it changed if needs be

Comment: @Clive I flagged one of his/her post as "In need of moderator intervention" . Please let me know if you want me to post the user profile link here too.

Comment: Thanks for that - I don't personally see anything wrong with that image so I'll defer to others' decisions

Comment: @Clive yes, that's why I hesitate to post user link here :) I'll keep intimate if I see any other such pics :)

Comment: Thanks @Krishna :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I recall, vulgar pictures are not allowed on Stack Exchange.

Flag a post made from that user, and use *in need of moderator intervention*, explaining what the problem is; the moderators will do the necessary.
Alternatively, if the user didn't write any post, open a question here and give a link to the user profile.

Comment: User has contributed some question/answers to the community. So I flagged a post made from that user as you said.